# How to find highest number from the vector provided?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, python-itertools

Say, a dictionary is provided with certain values.
How to find the highest number ?

**Input**

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
vector = 5

d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
vector = 5
l1 = list(td.values())
```

Based on vector value, it should print output.
vector is 5, so sum of the dict-values to form vector is `3,1,1`
Corresponding keys are `5,4,1`
so, the `output should be 541` *but slight change here*.
Since `value '1'` is associated with `multiple keys`, it should pick up `highest key`,
so, `output should be 544 instead of 541` (For above input, to brief about combinations without considering '1+1+1+1+1' to '44444')

**Another example**

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
  vector = 7
  Possible combinations:
  3  # --> Key of 7
  21 # --> Key of 6 & 1 (6+1 = 7)
  24 # --> Key of 6 & 1 (6+1 = 7)
  12 # --> Key of 1 & 6 (1+6 = 7)
  42 # --> Key of 1 & 6 (1+6 = 7)

  Output : 42 (Highest number)
```

**Another**

```
d1 = {1:9,2:4,3:2,4:2,5:6,6:3,7:2,8:2,9:1} 
vector = 5
here, it would be 1+2+2 (988). 
But, '1' can also be added 5 times to form vector 5, 
which would be '99999'
```

Since `@Patrick Artner` requested for minimal reproducible example, posting this though doesn't work as expected.

```
from itertools import combinations

def find_sum_with_index(l1, vector):
    index_vals = [iv for iv in enumerate(l1) if iv[1] < target]
    for r in range(1, len(index_vals) + 1):
        for perm in combinations(index_vals, r):
            if sum([p[1] for p in perm]) == target:
                yield perm


d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
vector=5
l1=list(d1.values())
for match in find_sum_with_index(l1, vector):
    print(dict(match))

Is there any specific algorithm to be chosen for these kind of stuffs ?
```

Comment: What is your problem. Do you have the algorythm that looks at the values and computes all possible partial sums to reach `vector`? [mre]?

Comment: @Patrick Artner:   Vector is nothing but sum. And from the dict-values, should find the combination that forms vector-sum. Then, should find the keys of those combinations (Highest value).

Comment: @PatrickArtner : I understand your concern of minimal reproducible example.

Comment: from itertools/combinations (list), you can get possible combinations to form  vector. d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3} , vector=5, , l1 = list(d1.values()) i.e., l1 = [1,6,7,1,3]. you would get result as {0:1,3:1,4:3} (from list, {index:element}). If you trace it back to get highest number forming vector would be 430 which is not right.Should be 544 wrt dictionary.

Comment: @PatrickArtner : Posted above and hope it's clear now.

Comment: Is a dict needed?  The key's appear to be indices.  A list should suffice right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the other answer but allowing repeatedly using the same keys to get the max number of keys which values sum up to vector:

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
vector = 7

#create a dict that contains value -> max-key for that value
d2 = {}
for k,v in d1.items():
    d2[v] = max(d2.get(v,-1), k)

def mod_powerset(iterable,l):
    # uses combinations_with_replacement to allow multiple usages of one value
    from itertools import chain, combinations_with_replacement
    s = list(set(iterable))
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations_with_replacement(s, r) for r in range(l))

# create all combinations that sum to vector
p = [ s for s in mod_powerset(d1.values(),vector//min(d1.values())+1) if sum(s) == vector]
print(p)
# sort combinations by length then value descending and take the max one
mp = max( (sorted(y, reverse=True) for y in p), key=lambda x: (len(x),x)) 

# get the correct keys to be used from d2 dict
rv = [d2[num] for num in mp]

# sort by values, biggest first
rv.sort(reverse=True)

# solution
print(''.join(map(str,rv)))
```

Original powerset - see [itertools-recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Answer (score 1):

There are some steps involved, see documentation in comments in code:

```
d1 = {1: 1, 2: 6, 3: 7, 4: 1, 5: 3}
vector = 7

# create a dict that contains value -> sorted key-list, used to get final keys
from collections import defaultdict
d2 = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in d1.items():
    d2[v].append(k)
for k,v in d2.items():
    d2[k] = sorted(v, reverse=True) 

from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(iterable):
    "see itertools: powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

# create all combinations that sum to vector
p = [ s for s in powerset(d1.values()) if sum(s) == vector]

# sort combinations by length then value descending and take the max one
mp = max( (sorted(y, reverse=True) for y in p), key=lambda x: (len(x),x)) 

# get the correct keys to be used from d2 dict
rv = []
for num in mp:
    rv.append(d2[num][0])
    # remove used key from list
    d2[num][:] = d2[num][1:]

# sort by values, biggest first
rv.sort(reverse=True)

# solution
print(''.join(map(str,rv)))
```

For powerset - see [itertools-recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But it prints, 541 for vector 5. Supposed to print 544 instead as i explained above.

Comment: @Stackguru - if you can use the keys multiple times, do not do `d2[num][:] = d2[num][1:]` to remove a once used key from d2 - you could simplify the creation of d2 a bit then by only remembering the maximum key for each value instead of storing the list of keys for each value

Comment: But here's some exception in this scenario, d1 = {1:9,2:4,3:2,4:2,5:6,6:3,7:2,8:2,9:1}
vector = 5 , here, it would be 1+2+2 (988). But, '1' can also be added 5 times to form vector 5, which would be '99999' as highest number.

Comment: @StackG then your question if badly specified - instead of using `{3,1,1}` to gain `5` you could also have done `{1,1,1,1,1}` all from the `4`-Key to get `44444` which is bigger then `644` by quite a lot.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Wanted to brief regarding combinations as well. I missed that. Thanks for correcting me.